# Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page - Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-toastr

Getting a Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document error when I run my protractor test to check the text in a toast pop up message.  I have tried element.all but so no avail:

My expect statement is

```
it('Delete toast pop up', function() {   
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
publisher_whitelist_page.deleteButtonClick();
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut'))),5000);
expect(element.all(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut')).getText()).toEqual('Ip address removed');
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Kirsty

**EDIT**

Bit of further progress getting the different error of Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Shaped it into a page object class:

```
this.popupToastIP = function(){
element.all(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut')).then(function(){
element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut')).getText();
```

});

and my expect:

```
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP),5000);
expect(publisher_whitelist_page.popupToastIP.toEqual('Ip address removed'));
```

again any advice would be appreciated at least it is finding it but can't read it!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your two last lines with:
`browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut')), 'Ip address removed'), 5000);`

Comment: Still getting the same error:  Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)

Comment: Try: `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` before wait.

Comment: Is this element blinking, or reloading? Another guess: replace `waitForAngular` with `browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(element(by.className('toast-success toast ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut'))),5000);`

Comment: Nope not reloading or blinking got the following error with what you suggested - Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: See my edit above - getting new error of not being able to read the bind

Comment: `bind` issue. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179354/6331748 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971548/6331748

Comment: No luck Kacper - have tried following advice of 2 different posts but no luck - still getting bind error.